# Create one service with BaseEntity to manage whole DB, .NET Core, EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.1

i don't have a particular problem, but the thing is i don't know if it is possible to create a service like this:

I have a abstract base class containing just an Id, and all classes (models from the DB) are inheriting from this class and have their properties.

My question is, can I have only one service, method that I can use to manage all my tables/models with CRUD operations?

Here is my Repository:

```
public class Repository : IRepository<db_context>
{
    private readonly db_context _dbContext;

    public Repository(db_context dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public T GetById<T>(int? id) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<T>().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    public List<T> List<T>() where T : BaseEntity
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public T Add<T>(T entity) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();

        return entity;
    }
    ....
}
```

Any ideas .. ?

Comment: Ditch the repository class entirrly. Entity framework is **already** both a repository *and* a unit or work. You are falling into a common anti-pattern/trap with EF

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible, I don't see why not. This is mainly because you are mostly just redoing what the DbContext already does. As *pinkfloydx33* mentioned, for the same reason I too would recommend not using one. Furthermore, this kind of abstraction never works in the long run. Along the line, you may need specific features which will start getting your code quite ugly and hard to maintain. If you were trying to create some form of simplification, you can also consider extension functions.

That being said, if you still have some reason to, once again it is very much possible. You can also use `_dbContext.Add(entity)` instead of `_dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity)` since `.Set<T>()` seems pointless in that instance (same for update).